# Creating a menu from a list using Jquery to just show the parent ul and current Level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to create a Menu from an list when the current link is identified with a span and I with to display the parent level and the current level on all branches as I navigate through the site. I am fairly new to scripting, any help found be greatly appreciated
Example
If the list was: 
A 
A b 
A b c 
A b

And the currentbranch span was on c. 
I would want the list to be: 
b 
b c 
b

-HTML List -

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="currentbranch0"><a href="/site/">Home</a></span>
    <ul class="multilevel-linkul-0">
        <li><a href="/site/news/">News</a>
        <ul class="multilevel-linkul-1">
            <li><a href="/site/news/internal/">Internal</a>
            <ul class="multilevel-linkul-2">
                <li><a href="/site/news/internal/archive/">Archive</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/site/news/external/">External</a>
            <ul class="multilevel-linkul-2">
                <li><a href="/site/news/external/archive/">Archive</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/site/news/poll/">News Poll</a></li>
            <li><a href="/site/news/allnews/">All News</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="currentbranch1"><a href="/site/locations/">Locations</a></span>
        <ul class="multilevel-linkul-1">
            <li><a href="/site/locations/a/">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="/site/locations/b/">b</a></li>
            <li><ahref="/site/locations/c/">c</a></li>
            <li><span class="currentbranch2"><a href="/site/locations/menutest/">Menu Test</a></span>
            <ul class="multilevel-linkul-2">
                <li><a href="/site/locations/menutest/test/">test</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
     (document).ready(function() {  var output = '<ul>';
output += $("#side_nav span").last().parent().parent().parent().parent().html();
        output += '</ul>';
        document.getElementById('side_nav').innerHTML = output;
    });$("#side_nav li").ready(function() {
    var count = [];
        $("#side_nav ul[class^='multilevel-']").each(function(){
            var item = $(this).attr('class')
            count.push(item);
            count.sort();
        });


        $('#side_nav li').each(function(){
        if($(this).parent('ul').hasClass(count[count.length-1])){

            $(this).remove();
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: i'm not sure what it is supposed to do but you can try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchgN/)

Comment: I've updated jsfiddle.

Comment: if i understand the question you want to only display the list items that contains a span with class currentbranch like this [http://jsfiddle.net/SchgN/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/SchgN/11/)

Comment: Hi. 
No I want to display the list items of the same level and the level above across the whole list. 
If the list was:
A 
A b 
A b c 
A b 
And the currentbranch span was on c. 
I would want the list to be 

b 
b c 
b

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/SchgN/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/SchgN/12/)